# Scala equivalent of java.util.Collection?

Tags: scala, collections

What is the equivalent of `java.util.Collection`? I first thought `Seq` is the way to go, but actually it's an ordered set of elements. I mean we have a numeration of elements.

Comment: `Traversable` and `Iterable` are the most general `traits` that Scala collections are build on.

Comment: The `Seq` interface is not an "ordered set of elements." It's a collection of elements that can be accessed in sequential order, only. The does not forbid nor require ordering.

Comment: But `Seq` retains ordering. Basically traversing a `Seq(1,2,3)` will always result in traversing in order `1 -> 2 -> 3`.

Comment: Also... `Collection` does not forbid from preserving order. So `Seq` qualifies as an alternative of `Collection` even if it preserves order. But `Traversable` will be closest to `Collection` from your point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Collection Hierarcy**

`Traversable` is on top above `iterable`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The picture above is very good looking, but it is not helpful at all in answering the question. (It may be helpful as general reference for other purposes, but not for this purpose.)  It is even missing some very important interfaces.  So, here is some good old text to try and clear out the confusion:

The Scala equivalent to `java.util.Collection` is `scala.collection.Iterable`, despite the mismatch in the name.

You see, `scala.collection.Iterable` offers the basic functionality of a Java `Collection`: it has an `iterator` and a `size`.

Apparently, what Java calls `Iterable` Scala calls it `Traversable`, and then what Java calls `Collection` Scala calls it `Iterable`.

Comment: From the perspective of interface features this might be correct, however `asJava(iterable` does not yield a collection.